# CollectionView SelectionChanged method not triggering when tapping the item directly .NET MAUI

Tags: collectionview, maui, selectionchanged

I'm creating a CollectionView in .net MAUI where i'm using Frame control inside the data template. As a result of that, when I tap directly on the item, the SelectionChanged method is not being triggered and will trigger only if I click on the frame border or outside of it. Below sample code and picture. Is this a bug in MAUI or I'm doing something wrong? I had the same setup in Xamarin and it was working with no issues.

XAML

```
 <CollectionView x:Name="scheduleItemsCollection" 
                                    SelectionChanged="scheduleItemsCollection_SelectionChanged"
                                    SelectionMode="Single"
                                  >
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                     Span="2"
                                     />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <Grid Padding="5" RowSpacing="0">

                                 <Frame CornerRadius="40" BorderColor="Gray"> 
                                        <StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="White">
                                            <Label  Text="{Binding bookingDayArabic}" />
                                            <Label   Text="{Binding bookingDateD}" />
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                              
                                                <Label Text="{Binding slotsAvailable}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                                <Label Text="عدد الطلبات:"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                             </Frame> 
                                </Grid>


                            </DataTemplate>

                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                    </CollectionView>
```

[image]

Comment: I've had some issues with Frame and stopped using it altogether. I replaced it with Border. It's more flexible than Frame and doesn't have bugs I encountered (there are some issues aroud it though). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border

Comment: Can you please specify what are these issues pertaining to the border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is the case as you said. Thanks for your support and feedback for maui.

I have created a new issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9567.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Section_Tapped"/>
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```